# If $v_1,..,v_n$ are linearly indpendent (LI) in $(V,\mathbb{F}')$, then they are LI in $(V,\mathbb{F})$ also.

Tags: vector-spaces, solution-verification

Say we have a fields $\mathbb{F}\subset
\mathbb{F}'$.

> If $v_1,..,v_n$ are linearly indpendent (LI) in
> $(V,\mathbb{F}')$, then they are LI in
> $(V,\mathbb{F})$ also.

Converse does not hold.

**Proof**: Write:
$$a_1v_1+a_2v_2+...+a_nv_n=0$$ where
$a_1,a_2,...a_n  \in\mathbb{F}$, so they are in $\mathbb{F}'$
Thus we have trivial linear combination in $(V,\mathbb{F}')$ where vectors are LI, so all $a_i$ are $0$ and thus given vectors are LI in $(V,\mathbb{F})$ also.

For converse we see that $(1,0)$ and $(\pi, 0)$ are LI in $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{Q})$ but in $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R})$ are not.

Now I wonder if

- the proof is correct and
- is $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{Q})$ vector subspace of $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Your proof looks correct to me. I would not call $(\Bbb R^2, \Bbb Q)$ a *subspace* of $(\Bbb R^2, \Bbb R)$, though. Simply because $(V, \Bbb F)$ is not a vector space or anything.

Comment: In fact, to talk about subspace, you need two vector spaces over the *same* field. Here you do not have that.

Comment: Aha, so it must be over the same field. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The proof is correct yes. A simpler example would be $1$ and $\pi$: they are linearly independent if we see $\Bbb R$ as a vector space over $\Bbb Q$, but not of you see it as a vector space over $\Bbb R$.

And, not $\Bbb R^2$ as a vector space over $\Bbb Q$ is not a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ as a vector space over $\Bbb R$. That's so because the concept of subspace is defined only for vector spaces over the same field.

Comment: So if $V\subset V'$ and vectors are LI in V then they are also in V'?

Comment: @User2020201 If the two vector spaces are over the same field, so that $V\subseteq V'$ makes sense the way it's discussed in this answer, then yes. Linear independence of a set of vectors is in some strict sense "independent" of exactly what space they are contained in. As in, expanding the space they lie in doesn't change whether they are linearly independent.

Comment: @User2020201 Now you're changing the base field again. We already addressed this, and $1,\pi$ is a counterexample.